# FileSystemTree itemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I've been trying to do a couple of things and I couldn't.

1. I've been trying to skin a mx:FileSystemTree, to show de data horizontally, I think it's almost impossible, anyone has an idea how to make it?
2. The second thing I'm trying is to add an itemRenderer to the FileSystemTree wanting to add a pair of buttons(add and delete, which I already had working). Everything I tried so far is giving the same error:
   `TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert SKins::FileSystemItemRenderer@971c479 to mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer.`

```
    <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                           width="750" height="500">
        
        
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:VGroup width="607" height="134">
            <s:HGroup width="607" height="68">
                <s:Button label="Button"/>
                <s:Button label="Button"/>
            </s:HGroup>
            <s:TextInput width="600"/>
        </s:VGroup>
        <mx:HDividedBox> 
            <mx:FileSystemTree id="tree" width="615" height="480" allowMultipleSelection="true"
                               borderVisible="false" defaultLeafIcon="@Embed('../assets/folder.png')"
                               directory="{new File(raiz)}" dragEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true"
                               folderClosedIcon="@Embed('../assets/folder.png')"
                               folderOpenIcon="@Embed('../assets/openFolder.png')" fontSize="45"
                               fontStyle="normal" fontWeight="normal" iconFunction="selectIcon"
                               itemRenderer="SKins.FileSystemItemRenderer" showIcons="true"
                               textAlign="left" textDecoration="none" verticalAlign="middle"/>    
            
        </mx:HDividedBox> 
        
    </s:WindowedApplication>
```

That's the code which is going to show the tree.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true">
    
    <s:Label text="{data}"/>
    
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

I have tried with a simple renderer receiving the error #1034.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/04/08/creating-an-alternating-item-renderer-in-a-spark-list-control-in-flex-4/ -->

<s:MXTreeItemRenderer name="IListItemRenderer"
                xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
        
    <s:HGroup id="hGr" left="4" right="4" top="4" bottom="4">
        <s:RichText id="lbl" text="({itemIndex}) {data.label}" width="100%" />
        <mx:Image id="img" source="{data.img}" toolTip="{data.img}" width="100" height="67" />
    </s:HGroup>
    
</s:MXTreeItemRenderer>
```

I also have tried another renderer, but with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about showing data horizontally, but your 2nd point about itemrenderer is working fine for me. Here is the working code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXTreeItemRenderer
                  xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<s:HGroup id="hGr" left="4" right="4" top="4" bottom="4">
    <s:Rect id="indentationSpacer"
            width="{treeListData.indent}" height="22"
            alpha="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFFF" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Group id="disclosureGroup">
        <s:BitmapImage source="{treeListData.disclosureIcon}"
                       width="16" height="16"
                       visible="{treeListData.hasChildren}" />
    </s:Group>
    <s:BitmapImage source="{treeListData.icon}"
                   width="16" height="16"/>
    <s:RichText id="lbl" text="{data.nativePath}" toolTip="{data.nativePath}" width="100%" maxDisplayedLines="1"  />

    <s:Button label="Button"/>
    <s:Button label="Button"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you man!!!. You save me from a headache!!! I don't know why it didn't work earlier, but your solution is great!! I just changed RichText for a Label, cause RichText wasn't showing, Thanks again.